# Notification Bar inside an app

Tags: android

I have something in mind that i would like to integrate into my android app and I dont know where to start researching.

I want to create a notification bar just as androids in my app, and hold an activity in it( eg. a menu ) and for it to dropdown when the user pulls it down just like android.

I didnt know what to exactly research about, i tried notification bar in android app but to no success as all the links go to customizing your android notification bar.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: exactly it . Thank you. Cheers!